# Minecraft Plugin | Creating NPC not working

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

i want to create an NPC with a command.

I've written this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {

    if (sender instanceof Player) {
        Player p = (Player) sender;

        if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("npc")) {
            if (args.length < 1) {
                sender.sendMessage("§cSyntax: /npc create [name]");
                return true;
            }

            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("create")) {

                if (args.length < 2) {
                    sender.sendMessage("§cSyntax: /npc create [name]");
                    return true;
                }

                sender.sendMessage("§4[§2Quests§4] §fNPC spawned.");


                MinecraftServer ms = (MinecraftServer) Bukkit.getServer();
                WorldServer ws = (WorldServer) p.getWorld();
                GameProfile gp = new GameProfile(UUID.randomUUID(), "NAME");

                EntityPlayer npc = new EntityPlayer(ms, ws, gp, new PlayerInteractManager(ws));

                Player npcPlayer = npc.getBukkitEntity().getPlayer();
                npcPlayer.setPlayerListName("");

                npc.setLocation(p.getLocation().getX(), p.getLocation().getY(), p.getLocation().getZ(), p.getLocation().getYaw(), p.getLocation().getPitch());

                PlayerConnection connection = ((CraftPlayer)p).getHandle().playerConnection;
                connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, npc));
                connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutNamedEntitySpawn(npc));

                return true;
            }

            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
                sender.sendMessage("§cSyntax: /npc delete");

                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

But it gives me an error here:

```
MinecraftServer ms = (MinecraftServer) Bukkit.getServer();
```

It says, that i cant convert Server to MinecraftServer. My tutorial showed it like that and it worked for him.

His code was:

`MinecraftServer ms = (MinecraftServer) Bukkit.getServer().getServer();`

But this double getServer() isn't avaiable anymore.

EDIT1:
I've used spigot 1.14.4 library.

I know that this tutorial is old, but I didn't found something else to spawn NPCs. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsvFOJWECGE

My goal is to create NPCs and to be able to click them.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to give a complete answer without knowing exactly which libraries you are using vs those that the tutorial is using. I'm assuming that  [this](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Bukkit.java) is your source for Bukkit.getServer() and [this](https://github.com/Bukkit/mc-dev/blob/master/net/minecraft/server/MinecraftServer.java) is the source for your MinecraftServer.

You can see from this that getServer() is a static method within Bukkit and returns a class that implements the [Server interface](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Server.java).

But from the second source we can see that MinecraftServer implements ICommandListener, Runnable and IMojangStatistics

As MinecraftServer does not implement the Server interface that Bukkit.getServer() implements then the compiler is unable to cast the return value of this call to MinecraftServer.

As for why the double getServer being unavailable - If we take a look at the [Server interface](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Server.java) that Bukkit.getServer() returns, we can see that it doesn't include a getServer() method, so you cannot call it. I can't say where the tutorial got it from.

If you are able to provide a link to the tutorial I can edit/modify this answer to better suit the situation.